# extract different level paramenter from param hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have a params hash :

```
{
 user_id:xxx,
 device:
 {
 type:xxx,
 name:xxx
 },
 ...
}
```

I want to get user_id, type, name. How can I get then with require and permit. Currently I'm using

```
params.require(:device).permit(:type,:name).tap{|p| p[:user_id] = params[:user_id]}
```

I'm finding a better way. Any help is appriciated :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One better way:

```
params.permit(:user_id).merge(params.require(:device).permit(:type, :name)
```